# Ubuntu 14.04 disconnects from the network via wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, adhoc, disconnect

Created a network on my desktop computer in windows 7 in mode "Ad-hoc" and tried to connect to it with laptop in ubuntu 14.04. Every time I tried to connect, identification status continues for some time and than ubuntu breaks off the connection. I had the message after disconnection from avahi-daemon about .local domain but when I managed with it nothing changed (but the message doesn't appear any more). 
PS. The network in "Infrastructure" mode works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Happened to me once, fixed it by switching the "Ad-Hoc" mode into "Infrastructure" mode. Try that. :)

Edit: "Ad-Hoc" mode only works for the personal user account that created the network in first place. Upon switching to ubuntu, it becomes read as a different user, even if it's actually the same computer. So word of advice, keep it on infrastructure.